# CSS style sheet not affecting my html file when I open it from my computer

Tags: html, css, file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="background.txt">

 </head>

 <body>

 </body>

  </html>
```

Content of `background.txt`:

```
 html { 
 background: url(desktop/dotcheese.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; 

 -webkit-background-size: cover;

 -moz-background-size: cover;

 -o-background-size: cover;

  background-size: cover;

  }
```

This is my code. imagine there are still the inequality symbol thingies behind each tag. when i open the html file it is blank, and does not show the background that i made in the css file. is it because i need to upload both files to the internet or is something wrong?

Comment: Css files usually end with .css

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would try to include some contents in the body tag, and set the CSS background properties to the body tag or an inner div, rather than the html tag. Also, why not rename the CSS file to .css?
Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="background.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test</p>
  </body>
</html>

body {
  background: url(desktop/dotcheese.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I think this should work.

Comment: thank you for your response but it is still not working :(

Comment: I suppose that the file you are trying to use as the background exists. You should double-check that. What happens if you remove the CSS3 background-size properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think the path to the background image is wrong. It appears you're trying to access a file that's on your desktop, but most likely the relative path isn't correct. Try moving all 3 files in a folder and change background: url(**desktop**/dotcheese.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed; to background: url(*dotcheese.jpeg*) no-repeat center center fixed;

Comment: it is still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the path to the CSS file is correct. I would place both HTML and CSS files in the same folder to try out. If it works, then the files could be put under different folders. Also, remember to give the Relative path for the CSS file.
2. Check if the path to the background image is correct.